# Set multiple alarms sequentially in Android

Tags: java, android, alarm

I want to set 2 alarms but only one is set! 
If I insert sleep between setting alarms it will works! does any one knows why it operates like this?

```
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
    alarmIntent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, "Alarm1");
    alarmIntent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, 17);
    alarmIntent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, 0);
    alarmIntent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_SKIP_UI, true);
    alarmIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(alarmIntent);

      try {
          Thread.sleep(10000);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      } 


    Intent alarmIntent2 = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
    alarmIntent2.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, "Alarm2");
    alarmIntent2.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, 18);
    alarmIntent2.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, 0);
    alarmIntent2.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_SKIP_UI, true);
    alarmIntent2.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(alarmIntent2);
```

Comment: Are you looking to start Alarm2 only when Alarm1 is completed?

Comment: Actually I just want to have 2 alarms one for 17:00 and another one for 18:00. when I tried to add them sequentially only one of them is set. But when I sleep(10000) before setting second alarm, the second alarm is set successfully too. I do not understand why is acts like that!